# Low frame rate when using zxing and camera2

Tags: android, zxing, frame-rate, android-camera2

I faced with a problem which I can't resolve yet. I am creating an application which must read qr with using of camera 2 api. I made it, but the frame rate is low. The problem is that I am using an ImageReader with big width and height frame resolution.

```
static ImageReader newInstance(int width, int height, int format, int maxImages)
```

I tried to reduce frame resolution but it leads to another problem. Zxing  stops reading qr codes or do that too slow. I am stuck. Tell me how to deal with this problem. Maybe I should try the Google Vision library? Will it help?

Comment: Google Vision lib is just for that. Give it a try. OTOH, I don't know why low frame rate should be a concern. It's worthless to be able to decode 60 QR codes per second.

Comment: @AlexCohn Tha low frame rate is a problem because it is a bad user experience. Suppose that camera is using both at the dark and at the light at the same time Change in lighting and low frame rate affects the eyes very badly. And finally it is my manager's wish P.S. Thank you for responding